# How should I design with React/Typescript: Server sends list of steps. Each step has a type and payload

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns

I'm looking for some good ideas on software design for this problem:

A server sends an array of Steps:

```js
type StepTypeEnum = 'SECURITY' | 'PERSONAL_DETAILS' | ... ;
type Step = { stepType: StepTypeEnum, payload: ??? };
StepsController.GET(): Array<Step>;
```

The client receives the array of steps and renders each step using React.

Each step has a different rendering component and payload type. For example:

```js
const Security = ({ username, password }) => <span>...</span>;
const PersonalDetails = ({ firstName, surName }) => <span>...</span>;
// etc...
```

What's the best way to implement it with typing?
The first ideas that comes to mind is the Factory pattern, but I'm not sure how to deal with the facts that `payload` can be of any type. Should I just type it as any and downcast it in the component?

For example, what I kind of have now:

```js
const Factory = step => ({
  SECURITY: ({payload}) => <Security username={payload.username} password={payload.password} />,
  PERSONAL_DETAILS = ({payload}) => <PersonalDetails firstName={payload.firstName} ... />
}[step.type])

const Component = Factory(step);
<Component payload={payload} />
```

This forces me to use `any` to describe the payload type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly common design pattern.  What you are doing is essential the same as what's described in this redux section on [type checking actions and action creators](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-actions--action-creators).

What you want to do is have a type for each specific pairing of `stepType` and `payload`.  You then define a generalized `Step` type as a union of all the valid pairings.  Now when you check if the `stepType` is `'SECURITY'`, typescript will know that the payload type can only be the type which goes with a security step. (Make sure you don't destructure before checking or this won't work).

We'll define the props/payload interfaces first because we can use the same interfaces for our steps as for our render components.

```
interface SecurityProps {
    username: string;
    password: string;
}

interface PersonalDetailsProps {
    firstName: string;
    surName: string;
}

const Security = ({ username, password }: SecurityProps) => 
    <span>{username}</span>;

const PersonalDetails = ({ firstName, surName }: PersonalDetailsProps) => 
    <span>{`${firstName} ${surName}`}</span>;
```

Now we create a union of steps.  We can define them individually and then combine, but I'm going to write and combine them in one step.  We can get your `StepTypeEnum` by looking at the `stepTypes` in our union, if you need this.

```
type Step = {
    stepType: 'SECURITY';
    payload: SecurityProps;
} | {
    stepType: 'PERSONAL_DETAILS';
    payload: PersonalDetailsProps;
}

type StepTypeEnum = Step['stepType'];
```

We need a component that can render any `Step`.  A map like what you have is fine but I'm going to use a `switch` instead as no extra typing is needed.  Our union type does all the heavy lifting.

```
const RenderStep = ({step}: {step: Step}) => {
    switch (step.stepType) {
        case 'SECURITY':
            return <Security {...step.payload} />; // knows that payload is SecurityProps
        case 'PERSONAL_DETAILS':
            return <PersonalDetails {...step.payload} />; // knows that payload is PersonalDetailsProps
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I ended up so ng